# Need to extract Genre from the Movie page on IMDb

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to extract a list of all the genres of any given movie from the movie page on IMDb.

For example:

- Movie page: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0454848/?ref_=adv_li_i
- List of Genres: [Crime, Drama, Mystery, Thriller]

I tried using Beautiful Soup but I am not able to find the exact class under which the genres are stored.

**Following are the snippets I tried:**

```
ul= soup.find("ul", {"class": "ipc-metadata-list ipc-metadata-list--dividers-all sc-388740f9-1 IjgYL ipc-metadata-list--base"})
children = ul.findChildren("a", recursive=False)
```

This throws an error saying `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findChildren'`

```
class_selector = "ipc-inline-list__item" 
genre = soup.find_all('li', {'class': class_selector})
list1 = []
for tag in list1:
   list1.append(tag.find('a')).text
print(list1)
```

This return a list with no entries

Any help would be great!

[Image of the website source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xxPA.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your Screenshot, to get the list of genre, you can use selenium with bs4 as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")


webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
url='https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0454848/?ref_=adv_li_i'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
t=soup.select_one('span.ipc-metadata-list-item__label:-soup-contains("Genres")').parent
genre=[x.get_text() for x in t.select('div[class="ipc-metadata-list-item__content-container"] > ul > li')]
print(genre)
```

**Output:**

```
['Crime', 'Drama', 'Mystery', 'Thriller']
```

Comment: That `maximize_window` is a more elegant solution than mine, scrolling an x number of pixels to get the page to pull the data. +1.

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need the overheads of selenium/chromedriver setup, instead you can do it with requests:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0454848/?ref_=adv_li_i')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
genres = soup.select_one('div.ipc-chip-list__scroller')
for genre in genres.contents:
    print(genre.text)
```

This prints out:

```
Crime
Drama
Mystery
```

BeautifulSoup documentation can be found at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

UPDATE: To get the desired genre list, you can use selenium only. I will include the full code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0454848/?ref_=adv_li_i'
# url = 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0765429/'

browser.get(url)
browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,2200);")
elem_pulled_from_graphql = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="storyline-plot-summary"]')))
genres = elem_pulled_from_graphql.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link']")
genres = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Genres']/following-sibling::div//child::li")))
for g in genres:
    print(g.text)
```

This will print out:

```
Crime
Drama
Mystery
Thriller
```

This solution is based on selenium only, and will wait as long as needed (well, up to 20 seconds) for the data to be pulled from database by the graphql query.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I tried running the code you sent but for some reason the list of genres is capped to 3 elements for all the movies I am trying. Is there any reason for the same? Is it possible to get a list of all genres?

Comment: Can you give an example with more than 3 genres, where you only get 3?

Comment: For the attached movie itself (Inside Man), there are 4 genres, Crime, Drama, Mystery and Thriller, but I only see Crime, Drama and Mystery printed on the console

Comment: No, there are only 3: https://ibb.co/9sQKCCX Crime, Drama, Mistery

Comment: Oh actually this was not the place I wanted to extract the data from. If you scroll down on the same page, there is a list of all the genres that the movie belongs to, as shown in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xxPA.png

Comment: That data is being loaded by javascript, via a graphql call to https://caching.graphql.imdb.com/?operationName=TMD_Storyline&variables=%7B%22titleId%22%3A%22tt0454848%22%7D&extensions=%7B%22persistedQuery%22%3A%7B%22sha256Hash%22%3A%22cbefc9c4a2dbd0a5583e223e5bc788946016db709a731c85251fc1b1b7a1afbe%22%2C%22version%22%3A1%7D%7D. You would need to either scrape that, either use the api offered for free by imdb.

Comment: I added a (pure) selenium solution as well. This will wait for the data to be loaded in page (up to 20 seconds, if needed) and print out the genres.

Answer (score 1):

To extract list of all the genres i.e. *Crime*, *Drama*, *Mystery* and *Thriller* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0454848/?ref_=adv_li_i'})
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-testid='storyline-genres'] a.ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item.ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0454848/?ref_=adv_li_i'})     
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@data-testid='storyline-genres']//a[@class='ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item ipc-metadata-list-item__list-content-item--link']")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['Crime', 'Drama', 'Mystery', 'Thriller']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for replying! I'm able to extract the top 3 genres from the methods you suggest but I'm looking for an exhaustive list of genres as mentioned when you scroll down on the same page. The exhaustive list is mentioned in this part of the page i.stack.imgur.com/8xxPA.png

Comment: Although your code does not give me the list of Genres, it does give me the list of keywords which is another data point I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm, I don't visit urls really because as per SO standards we expect OP to provide the text based HTML, so contributors can test their code before publishing as answers. Updated the answer.

Comment: Will keep that in mind before asking another question on SO!