How can I scrape the genres from a movie's IMDB page using rvest?
I'm trying to scrape the standard data (title, year, rating, genres) from an IMDB's page for a movie and I am stuck at genres. There isn't a .genre class like there used to be (and is commonly used in the online tutorials/how-tos) and I am not well-versed enough in rvest to figure out how to collect the data. Below is the code that is mostly chatgpt-generated, and I've been troubleshooting it.
How can I grab the genres? Any help would be appreciated.

# Load necessary libraries
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

# Function to scrape movie information from IMDB
scrape_imdb <- function(movie_names) {
  base_url <- "https://www.imdb.com/find?q="
  
  # Initialize an empty data frame to store the results
  results_df <- data.frame(Movie = character(),
                           Year = character(),
                           Rating = character(),
                           Genres = character(),
                           Runtime = character(),
                           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  for (movie_name in movie_names) {
    # Construct search URL
    search_url <- paste0(base_url, URLencode(movie_name), "&s=tt")
    
    # Read the search result page
    search_page <- read_html(search_url)
    
    # Extract the first movie result's URL
    movie_url <- search_page %>%
      html_nodes(".ipc-metadata-list-summary-item__c a") %>%
      html_attr("href") %>%
      .[1] %>%
      paste0("https://www.imdb.com", .)
    
  
    movie_year <- search_page %>%
      html_nodes(".ipc-metadata-list-summary-item__c span")  |> 
      html_text() %>%
      .[1]
    
      # Read the movie page
    movie_page <- read_html(movie_url)
       

    movie_rating <- movie_page %>%
      html_nodes(".sc-bde20123-1.cMEQkK") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      .[1]
    
    movie_runtime  <- movie_page %>%
      html_nodes(".sc-d8941411-2.cdJsTz li") %>%
      html_text() %>% 
      .[3]
    
    movie_genres <- movie_page %>%
      html_element('[data-testid="storyline-genres"] div') |> 
      html_text()
      # paste(collapse = ", ")

    
    print(movie_genres)

    
    # Append the results to the data frame
    results_df <- rbind(results_df, data.frame(Movie = movie_name,
                                               Year = as.numeric(movie_year),
                                               Rating = as.numeric(movie_rating),
                                               # Genres = movie_genres,
                                               Runtime = movie_runtime,
                                               stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  }
  
  return(results_df)
}

# Example usage
movie_names <- c("The Matrix", "Inception", "Interstellar")

movie_info <- scrape_imdb(movie_names)

print(movie_info)


There are other questions about scraping genres. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73187207/need-to-extract-genre-from-the-movie-page-on-imdb. Based on that, rather than using html_element('[data-testid="storyline-genres"] div'), use html_elements("div.ipc-chip-list__scroller a")

The following code :
html <- read_html("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10838180/")
html %>% 
  html_elements(xpath = "//a[@role='button'][contains(@href,'genre')]") %>% 
  html_text()

will output :
[1] "Action" "Sci-Fi"

